# Detect if a View's WebView is already Loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

One of the tabs in my app loads a webpage that changes periodically.  Because of this, I have the ViewController load the webView in viewWillAppear.  The problem is I don't want the webView to load every time, just when it is the first time to load, or when the webView is different.  So, I have this setup:

```
 NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [worship request];
NSURL *currentURL2 = [currentRequest URL];
if (currentURL.absoluteString == nil) {
//loads the page
}
else {
//page is already loaded, do nothing more
}
```

The issue is that because of it checking for a url, it takes it a few seconds to go from one tab to another.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a boolean property like webViewLoaded to YES.
and keep it NO in the init method.

check its value and load the webview and modify the value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the best solution, but you could check if the url of the webView request is not nil and equals your previous "selected" url in viewDidLoad

```
NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
if([currentURL isEqualToString:myURL]) {
...//put boolean
}
```

And if the string equals, put it in an boolean.
In viewWillAppear you then check the boolean...